# Why webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd are getting "The transfer has triggered web application firewall"

Tags: c#

I have a web application which working fine from our internal net work and also accessible from public internet but, when I try to access from internet the hovering over the main menu is not working, post back also showing error.
At last I discovered that the issue is from these two files(webresource.axd & scriptresource.axd) and when I try to access any one of them from URL I get the following alert "The transfer has triggered a Web Application Firewall the transfer is blocked".
I followed many suggestions with no benefit.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [ASP.NET AXD resources getting blocked at client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364442/asp-net-axd-resources-getting-blocked-at-client-side)